# Top N Filter - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to achieve Top N Filter in page and report level which are associated with multiple visuals? I can't seem to figure it out. Please suggest a method which can help me do this.

Comment: Can you please show your sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can [parameterize Top N filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73107411/6165594) through measure.

**pros**: if Top N value should be changed, you just change it in one place

**cons**: you still have to add this measure to each visual...