# Power Bi: how to parameterize Top N visual level filter

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, top-n

Since `PowerBI` don't support `Top N` filter on `page level`,
I want to **use N as a parameter** to change it at once per multiple visuals.
Is it possible?

[image]

P.S.In [**this video (9:15)**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVvlEHKr_0o&t=555s&ab_channel=SQLBI) solution for more complex case is provided.

In the end of [this article](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-the-top-products-alongside-the-other-products-in-power-bi/) sample file available

Comment: Are you asking for just TopN or TopN and Others which is wildly more complicated depending on your use case.

Comment: @David, Just Top N. Exactly as on screen, but using DAX code, NOT GUI

Comment: I'll post an answer below

Comment: @David, in some cases still don't work as estimated (output is not identical to TopN visual level filter). The details (example+file) shared in description above. Could you please help?

Comment: It might be better to post a brand new question so others can also help debug your specific problem.

Comment: @David, [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73175886/6165594)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sample dataset, insert a new parameter.

Add a measure as follows:

```
Measure = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Product Name]) IN 
    SELECTCOLUMNS( 
        TOPN(
            [Parameter Value], 
            ADDCOLUMNS( ALLSELECTED( 'Product'),"@Sales", [Sales Amount] ), 
            [@Sales]
            ), 
        "x", 
        'Product'[Product Name]), 
1)
```

Every visual you want affected by the TopN should have this filter.

[image]

That's it.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested and it works fine. I'll update with a screenshot.

Comment: [Parameter Value] is added automatically when you create a new parameter.

Comment: Could you please use source file without data refresh and share screen with slicer filters selected? (I just have much smaller totals and can't reproduce your result)

Comment: I used the source file you posted without refreshing. I'll upload somewhere for you now

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/29949ebb9f62c175ae13d6c919dbe6df20220725135411/d0455e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246740/discussion-between-denis-and-david).

Comment: Updated to ALLSELECTED() to account for user filters.

Comment: If I want to get not Top but Bottom N...
As far as I understand, I just should add "ASC" in the end op TOPN....
But matrix don't return any rows then....
Could you please help?

Comment: The reason you get no rows returned is that you have lots of products with no sales.

Comment: Not exactly, because I put Sales>0 on visual filter. Moreover, if I put to matrix Measure - it displays ones correctly for products. But when I apply visual filter "is not blank" for measure, matrix becomes empty

Comment: I tested it and that is the reason. The filtering is happening within the topN. Change [Parameter Value] to a high number to check

Comment: Still not clear how to get Bottom 3 instead of Top 3...

Comment: Measure = 
IF(
    SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Product Name]) IN 
    SELECTCOLUMNS( 
        
        TOPN(
            [Parameter Value], 
            FILTER(ADDCOLUMNS(  ALL( 'Product'),"@Sales", [Sales Amount] ),  [@Sales] > 0 ), 
            [@Sales], ASC
            ) ,
        "x", 
        'Product'[Product Name]) ,
1)

Answer (score 0):

From usability perspective it's preferable to return Sales Rank in measure.

Solution below is a copy/paste from [SQLBI experts solution](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-the-top-products-alongside-the-other-products-in-power-bi/) with minimal code changes ( `ALLSELECTED ( 'Product'[Product Name]` ) replaced by `ALLSELECTED ( 'Product' )` ):

```
rnkSales = 
    IF (
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Product'[Product Name] ),
        VAR ProductsToRank = [TopN Value]
        VAR SalesAmount = [Sales Amount]
        RETURN
            IF (
                SalesAmount > 0,
                VAR VisibleProducts =                 
                    FILTER(     -- filters out data with no sales
                        CALCULATETABLE (
                            VALUES ( 'Product' ),
                            ALLSELECTED ( 'Product')   -- Use this if VisualFilterTopN equivalent required
                            //ALLSELECTED ( 'Product'[Product Name] ) -- Original code - returns TopN per dimension
                        ),
                        NOT ISBLANK( [Sales Amount] ) -- looks more universal then [Sales Amount]>0 (if calculation for Margin required, it could be negative)
                    )
                VAR Ranking =
                    RANKX (
                        VisibleProducts,                    
                        [Sales Amount],
                        SalesAmount
                    )
                RETURN
                    IF (
                        Ranking > 0 && Ranking <= ProductsToRank,
                        Ranking
                    )
            )
    )
```

[image]