# Power Bi: Top N visual level filter as Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure, top-n

Need a measure that will provide the same output as TopN visual level filter (than I can parameterize it).

The solution for simple cases provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73080480/6165594)

But it doesn't work for more complicated cases...

**EXAMPLE:**

Don't work if you add any dimension that has Many to One `Product Name` relationship (`Order Number` for example).

Desired output: both tables (top and bottom) should be equal:
[image]
[image]

Example from screen available here [HERE](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/main/Questions/how%20to%20parameterize%20Top%20N%20visual%20level%20filter.pbix)

**NB!** From usability perspective it's preferable to return Sales Rank in measure.

Comment: Not yet (tight schedule this week). But yesterday I got idea to try using RELATEDTABLE ([video from Mr.Ferrari 9:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NbbE39gwVVo&t=540s&ab_channel=SQLBI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit reworked solution from [David Bacci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218260/6165594):

**1.** If you need just **TopN Sales**:

```
TopnSalesAmount = 
VAR param = [TopN Value]
VAR topNTable =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        TOPN ( param, 'Product', [Sales Amount], ASC ),        
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Product'[Product Name] ),
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Sales ), [Sales Amount] <> BLANK () )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        NOT ( ISEMPTY ( Sales ) ),
        IF (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Product'[Product Name] )
                IN SELECTCOLUMNS ( topNTable, "a", 'Product'[Product Name] ),
            [Sales Amount]
        )
    )
```

[image]

**2.** If you need **Rank** for TopN Sales:

```
rnkTopnSalesAmount = 
IF (
  //ISINSCOPE ( 'Product Names'[Product Name]), -- depends, which one is used in visual
    ISINSCOPE ( 'Product'[Product Name] ) 
    && NOT ( ISEMPTY ( Sales ) ), 

    VAR ProductsToRank = [TopN Value]
    VAR topNTable =
        CALCULATETABLE (
            TOPN (
                ProductsToRank,
                ADDCOLUMNS ( VALUES ( 'Product'[Product Name] ), "@Amt", [Sales Amount] ),
                [Sales Amount], ASC
            ),
            FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( Sales ), [Sales Amount] <> BLANK () )
        )
    RETURN
        IF (
            SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Product'[Product Name] )
                IN SELECTCOLUMNS ( topNTable, "a", 'Product'[Product Name] ),
            RANKX ( topNTable, [@Amt], [Sales Amount], ASC )
        )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

[image]

[image]

```
BottomN = 

VAR param = [TopN Value]
VAR topNTable =  CALCULATETABLE( TOPN(param,'Product', [Sales Amount], ASC), ALLSELECTED('Product'[Category],'Product'[Product Name]), FILTER(allselected(Sales), [Sales Amount] <> BLANK()))
RETURN 
IF(NOT(ISEMPTY(Sales)),IF( SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Product Name]) IN SELECTCOLUMNS( topNTable,"a", 'Product'[Product Name]) ,[Sales Amount]))
```

Comment: Just works! :)  Thank you!
P.S. I removed `'Product'[Category]` form `ALLSELECTED` - this measure could be used in other visuals with other set of `Product` dimensions

Comment: Good stuff. Don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: accepted solution should provide Sales Rank in measure, [like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73126132/6165594)

Comment: I think I'll leave it to someone else then. My code should be enough for someone to build on.